# Get parent row of checkbox

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a checkbox column in my data table. To log any changes, I have defined an on click event. I also need another column's data from the same row.

```
<tr class="odd" role="row">
    <td class=" center">
        <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="row_check">
    </td>
    <td>2013-04-24 18:17:21</td>
    <td>1351710457</td>
</tr>

table.find('tbody').on( 'click', 'input', function ()
{
    var invite_id  = table.api().row(this.closest('tr')).data()[2]; // returns undefined
    // data processing after wards
});
```

The `closest()` and `parent()` functions always return undefined. In firefox, firebug characterizes both functions themselves as undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jquery object in order to get the jquery methods. Currently you are using dom object.

Replace `this` with `$(this)`

```
table.find('tbody').on('click', 'input', function() {
    var invite_id = table.api().row($(this).closest('tr')).data()[2];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way, as for me it's more readable to do the chaining than nesting.

```
table.find('tbody').on('click', 'input', function() {
    var invite_id = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
});
```